# Select Checkbox inside a ListView programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

How can I select a `CheckBox` inside a `ListView` via code?
I found some code online to check the boxes but checked property is not available in windows phone 8.1

```
foreach (ListViewGroup grp in listFiles.Groups)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in grp.Items)
    {
        if (item.Index != 0)
        {
            item.Checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

the xaml code is

```
<ListView x:Name="ContentListView" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding}" FontSize="25"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The checkboxes are automatically generated checkboxes of listview

Comment: The `Checked` property is available on `CheckBox`, in this code you are however iterating `ListViewItems`, not `CheckBoxes`. Without your view (e.g. XAML) it's impossible to guess where your `CheckBoxes` really are.

Comment: Are you not following MVVM design?

Comment: the checkboxes are automatic added check box....i am using list view in multiselect mode..

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer thanks for the respose,added the xaml..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add item which you want to be checked to the ListView's  `SelectedItems` list

```
foreach(var item in MyListView.Items)
{
    MyListView.SelectedItems.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by using the MVVM pattern. With MVVM you will seperate your business models & logic from the view. When implemented correctly you can modify your data and it will automaticly update the view.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg521153%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a link that contains a walkthrough about how to use it. It also contains an example using the checkbox.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.the function that i want is that when the user click on check box 'All' rest of the checkboxes get automatically selected

Comment: Where does checkbox All comes from?Is it one of the multiselect listviewitem

Comment: Ok when you check on ALL checkbox all other checkboxes get checked right?

Comment: i want to get them checked when ALL checkbox is checked...in the itemsource of the listview i am passing a list of strings..

Comment: I would suggest converting the list of strings to an object that contains a boolean and a string.